# Getting the AREA of an OIL SPILL

Tags: area

How much area in $m^2$ will $200 cm^3$ of oil cover if it forms a layer of $35mm$ thick?

i dont know what formula i will be using, my teacher never discussed this and i cant seem to find any on the internet, thanks.

Comment: $h=0.35$ mm, and no matter what shape the oil takes, as long as its uniform in thickness, we can write $A \cdot h=V$ where $A$ is the area and $V = 200$ cm$^3$ is the volume. You need to be careful with the different units, but I'm sure you've been taught how to work with them

Comment: thank u so much for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- For a cylinder or prism, volume is base area multiplied by height
- This implies base area would be volume divided by height
- These calculations are often easier if you use the same base unit throughout (except in the land of the *[acre-foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acre-foot)*)